# Can't enable secure boot in Windows 11

Tags: windows, bios, windows-11, secure-boot

I am using Windows 11 and can't enable secure boot. I tried to enable it in BIOS, but it still doesn't work, and in system information, it's off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You seem to have accidentally created two accounts: This [one](https://superuser.com/users/1718928/szymon) and this [one](https://superuser.com/users/1718931/szymon). Go to [this form](https://superuser.com/contact) and select the “I need to merge user profiles” and fill out the rest of the form to merge accounts.

Comment: I included in my post (a) ensuring BIOS changes are saved and (b) updating BIOS.  This will rewrite BIOS which may correct issues.

Answer (score 0):

Your BIOS status shows Secure Boot is Enabled.

Look here (screen shot) at Secure Boot State.

[image: Secure Boot State]

If it shows OFF, start in BIOS (UEFI) and ensure (a) Secure Boot is enabled AND (b) that you save changes  (usually Save and Exit to restart).

You may need to Reset BIOS to Default Settings and save again.

You may also wish to update BIOS (UEFI) to the most recent update. BIOS update rewrites BIOS (UEFI) and may correct minor errors (if any) in BIOS.

Finally, if all the above does not work, your computer may not be completely compatible with Windows 11.

Are you by chance running Windows 11 Insider? Or, did you use the registry entry to run Windows 11 even though it lacks all the features.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable the secure boot once and then save and exit and then again enable it that fixed this issue for me